# Google-analytics session count issue

Tags: google-analytics, angular7

I am logged in the application, when refresh the page from browser by f5 or Ctrl + f5 session count is up ticking(going up) . It should not add count since my session is not expired.

Sessions is counting when refreshing the page i have seen counts increasing in google analytics website

NA

Sessions count should not be changes if session is active

Comment: Have you used the default implementation? Need a bit more information to help. Have you pasted tracking code into the head? Are you using google tag manager?

Comment: Version used : Angular: 7.2.15, angulartics2 - https://www.npmjs.com/package/angulartics2

Comment: Yes, I am using GTM and Google analytics both in ANgular 7 project.

Comment: Have you pasted tracking code into the head? -- Yes